# Naming iterative Rmarkdown documents

Tags: r, for-loop, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to create multiple Rmarkdown documents (i.e., letters) that contain all the same text but are addressed to different people and have some unique text for each person. I've been taking a similar approach as the one laid out here:

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_mail_merge.html

Basically, I have an R script that creates the Rmarkdown pdfs:

```
## Packages
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

## Data
personalized_info <- read.csv(file = "meeting_times.csv")

## Loop
for (i in 1:nrow(personalized_info)){
rmarkdown::render(input = "mail_merge_handout.Rmd",
output_format = "pdf_document",
output_file = paste("handout_", i, ".pdf", sep=''),
output_dir = "handouts/")
}
```

and a .Rmd file to fill in the text below:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
personalized_info <- read.csv("meeting_times.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
name <- personalized_info$name[i]
time <- personalized_info$meeting_time[i]
```

Dear `r name`,

Your meeting time is `r time`.

See you then!
````

When I run the above R script, I get a folder named "handouts," with files named "handout_1," "handout_2," etc. I would like the files to be named after the person in the dataset, and to do this I changed "i" to "name" under the loop heading of the code. This produces files named like "handout_Ezra Zanders," but the file name does not much the name of the person in the Rmarkdown pdf.

Anyone know of a solution for this in the loop part of the script, or another way of doing this?

Comment: Looks like you are relying on the value of the iterator (`i`) in the global environment. Safer would be to use a parameterized report, see here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html. Perhaps that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the names in your `i` loop. By the way, because you are using an external script to run your markdown, it is not necessary to read again the csv file in the mardown.

The R script that creates the Rmarkdown pdfs:

```
## Packages
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

## Data
personalized_info <- read.csv(file = "meeting_times.csv")

## Loop
for (i in 1:nrow(personalized_info)) {
  name <- personalized_info$name[i]
  time <- personalized_info$meeting_time[i]
  rmarkdown::render(input = "mail_merge_handout.Rmd",
    output_format = "pdf_document",
    output_file = paste("handout_", name, ".pdf", sep=''),
    output_dir = "handouts/")
}
```

and a .Rmd file to fill in the text below:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

Dear `r name`,

Your meeting time is `r time`.

See you then!
```